# Change the block background color

Tags: faces, coloring

My question is how to customize this kind of blocks' background color?

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question might helpful for you: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/change-the-background-color-of-specific-block

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what "*this kind of block*" means, or how your "blocks" were caused/created.

Anyway, it sounds like you are asking how to know which face is used for that text with the yellow background, so you can use `M-x customize-face` to change its appearance.

The answer to that is to put the cursor somewhere on that highlighted text and use `C-u C-x =`.  The `*Help*` output will tell what faces are used at that position, for both text property `face` and overlay property `face`.