# Problem when highlighting region using hlt-highlight-region

Tags: highlighting

The thing I want to do is to highlight regions in a file covered by jest JavaScript tests. For testing I'm in an `.emacs` buffer, and I'm trying to highlight a single line in another buffer that I have opened in a different window.

I was looking at [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/change-the-background-color-of-specific-block), which uses `hlt-highlight-region` from library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary), but I'm not able to make this work.

I have code like this that should change the single line's background to green:

```lisp
  (let* ((dir "/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/terminal/repo")
         (buffer (get-file-buffer (concat dir "/js/jquery.terminal-src.js")))
         (start '((line . 3156) (column . 0)))
         (end '((line . 3156) (column . 18))))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (let* ((start-line-pos (line-beginning-position (cdr (assoc 'line start))))
             (start-pos (+ start-line-pos (cdr (assoc 'column start))))
             (end-line-pos (line-beginning-position (cdr (assoc 'line end))))
             (end-pos (+ end-line-pos (cdr (assoc 'column end)))))
        (hlt-highlight-region start-pos end-pos '((t (:background "green")))))))
```

But the code is returning `nil` and nothing happens. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Your problem is not **`(hlt-highlight-region N1 N2 '((t (:background "green")))`**, at least. If you just do that, with two buffer positions for `N1` and `N2` then you'll see that it works. Try inserting `(message "START: %S, END: %S" start-pos end-pos)` just before the call to `hlt-highlight-region`, to see what values those vars have. Or use `M-x debug-on-entry` followed by the name of your function, and walk through the debugger with `d` or `c` to see what happens.

Comment: @Drew I've investigated and it seems that line-begninning-position is not accepting line number as argument maybe it's offset or something.

Comment: `line-beginning-position` accepts a number of lines to move. It returns the buffer position of the beginning of the line that it arrives at after that move. (The move is temporary/simulated - point is left where it was initially.) If you want the position of the beginning of the current line then don't pass an argument.